# JTree component in java swing

Tags: swing, icons, jtree

How can I change the icon of nodes and root in the `JTree` component of Swing?

Answer (score 2):

With a [`DefaultTreeCellRenderer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeCellRenderer.html) use `setClosedIcon`, `setOpenIcon` and `setLeafIcon`.

Copied from [How to Use Trees](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html):

```
ImageIcon leafIcon = createImageIcon("images/middle.gif");
if (leafIcon != null) {
    DefaultTreeCellRenderer renderer = 
    new DefaultTreeCellRenderer();
    renderer.setLeafIcon(leafIcon);
    tree.setCellRenderer(renderer);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sun's [Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) on JTree has a section on how to subclass TreeCellRenderer to get nodes and text in a JTree.

Answer (score 0):

If all you trying to do is to have different Icons for closed node, leaf and opened nodes, it is very straight forward.

//Create 3 icons
  private Icon customOpenIcon = new ImageIcon("images/my_open.gif");
  private Icon customClosedIcon = new ImageIcon("images/my_closed.gif");
  private Icon customLeafIcon = new ImageIcon("images/my_leaf.gif");

//Assuming you created your DefaultMutableTreeNode hierarchy
    DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode = new...
    ...
    JTree tree = new JTree(rootNode );

```
DefaultTreeCellRenderer customRenderer = new DefaultTreeCellRenderer();
customRenderer.setOpenIcon(customOpenIcon);
customRenderer.setClosedIcon(customClosedIcon);
customRenderer.setLeafIcon(customLeafIcon);
tree.setCellRenderer(customRenderer );
```

Comment: i tried to use DefautTreeCellRenderer, but my class doesnt recognaize it, i use eclipse 3.2